# Issue displaying map in GMSMapView outlet

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am following Google's tutorial and things are working fine except I can't make the map display in the GMSMapView outlet. How can I do that?

Code in viewDidLoad():

```
 locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapView
```

and the outlet declaration is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView!
```

The outlet is connected from the interface UIView that type was changed to GMSMapView.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

do you have this in appdelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function ?

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
```

where googleMapsApiKey is your google ios api key

Comment: yes I do have that...as I said the map displays properly with marker...but not when I want to show it in the GMSMapView....I am sure am doing something wrong in regards to assigning the map to the GMSMapView

Comment: Then you should check googleMapView frame. You can use viewdebugger, to make sure that the problem is displaying the map and not misplacement of the view.